# Spark Dataframe - Computation of pairs between columns (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following situation: I have a dataframe with an 'id' and 'array' as the schema. Now I want to get for each array, all lists of pairs with the corresponding id and save it again in a dataframe. So for example:

This is the original dataframe:

```
+---+----------+
| id|candidates|
+---+----------+
|  1|    [2, 3]|
|  2|       [3]|
+---+----------+
```

And that is how it have to look like after the computation:

```
+---+---+
|id1|id2|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
|  2|  3|
+---+---+
```

Maybe someone has an idea for this problem?

Comment: Simply use the [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) function

Comment: And how I can use it for all array elements?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks @cheseaux I found the answer! There is the simply explode_outer function:

```
    candidatesDF.withColumn("candidates", explode_outer($"candidates")).show
```

Comment: Use `explode` if you don't want any row when the array is null/empty. if you use `explode_outer` it will in that case produce `null`, which might not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `explode` the array column.

```
candidatesDF.withColumn("id2", explode('candidates))
```